# How to find the position or location of string in given document

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, position

How to find the position or location of string in given document.I have one word document and i want to store all its words and word positions in database so thats why i need to find the position of the words.

so please tell me how can i find position or location of word or string in given document.

i intend to use vb.net or c# for and .doc documents

Comment: Instead of storing all the positions?  Have you considered dynamically calculating the positions of some words or text.  Just seems like going through a document and storing the positions of all words is tedious

Comment: yes..
well for a start i need to be able to fine each position then remove "stopwords" and store the postions i really need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm... I haven´t found a more smart solution :-/ but maybe this helps you... We´ll suppose that you have some version of MS Office installed in your system.

First of all, you have to add a reference in your project to a Microsoft COM component called "Microsoft Word  ?* object library"

*? It deppends of the version of your MS Office

After you´ve added the reference, you could test this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Word;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Find the full path of our document

            System.IO.FileInfo ExecutableFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);            
            object docFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ExecutableFileInfo.DirectoryName, "document.doc");

            // Create the needed Word.Application and Word.Document objects

            object nullObject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Word.Application application = new Word.ApplicationClass();
            Word.Document document = application.Documents.Open(ref docFileName, ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject);


            string wholeTextContent = document.Content.Text; 
            wholeTextContent = wholeTextContent.Replace('\r', ' '); // Delete lines between paragraphs
            string[] splittedTextContent = wholeTextContent.Split(' '); // Get the separate words

            int index = 1;
            foreach (string singleWord in splittedTextContent)
            {
                if (singleWord.Trim().Length > 0) // We don´t need to store white spaces
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Word: " + singleWord + "(position: " + index.ToString() + ")");
                    index++;
                }
            }

            // Dispose Word.Application and Word.Document objects resources

            document.Close(ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject);
            application.Quit(ref nullObject, ref nullObject, ref nullObject);
            document = null;
            application = null;

            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I´ll test it and it looks that it works =)

Comment: thanks alot it works .....

i just increased the missing agrument to 16 cos of my version of word COM
and it needs a few touches as it only  displays the last paragraph of any document 

thanks so so much tho

Comment: While I was writing this awfull code I thought a good idea would like to learn more about open office libraries for .NET...

Comment: not a bad idea boss ....at the moment am neck deep in projects
thanks alot again for the help 
i have added stopword removal and able to save what i need in the database

ps.
in the code above am trying to change the filename dynamicaly from an aspx page using process.start and geting the values from main()
but no luck yet .